# Is there a way to populate bsmultiselect with ajax?

Tags: javascript, bsmultiselect

Is there a way to populate bsmultiselect - https://dashboardcode.github.io/BsMultiSelect/ with ajax? So I could use pagination, querying, limits etc? With select2 there is something like

```
$('#select').select2({
ajax: {
  url: '/api/data',
  data: function(params) {...
```

Would be glad for any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `options` property

Comment: Yes. Use your data from the server to dynamically create/populate a `<select ... multiple>` and apply the jQuery plugin to it.

Comment: Yea, that's obvious. But i would like to be able to limit the first load to for example 10 records. Then allow users to write into the component and automatically call ajax with search. Now I am only able to populate it at first load, then use some trigger like onkeyup and recreate the whole thing. This is a bad approach imho. So trying to find a new-better way